# Reading computed CGPoints from a plist

Tags: swift, plist, cgpoint

I’m looking for a way to load computed CGPoints from a plist (Xcode 6 / Swift).

I used to enter CGPoints as Strings into the plist in the format {160,450}, load the string and convert it with CGPointFromString().

Since I want the app to work on different devices I’d need these CGPoints to be relative to the screen size.

I thought it would be possible to enter a string as {kScreenWidth/2, kScreenHeight * 3/4} but of course, that doesn’t work and returns CGPointZero.
I guess I could write my own CGPointFromString method that takes my constants into account but I don't know how to do that and there may be a better solution without strings.

Is it possible to save and load this as “Data” in the plist?
I’ve tried a lot but can’t seem to find the solution.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Here’s the code:

```
let points: [CGPoint]

init(levelNumber: Int) {
  let levelDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("level\(levelNumber + 1)", ofType: "plist")!)! {

  self.points = []

  if let pointsData = levelDict["pointsData"] as [NSDictionary]? 
    for item in pointsData {
      let pointString = item["point"] as String
      self.points.append(CGPointFromString(pointString))
    }
  }
}
```

Then I would create a CGPath from the points array (know how to do that).

EDIT: Just a quick update to make my intentions clearer.

I need to create paths that will be the same on all devices, relative to their screen sizes. The CGPoints for the path should be entered manually into a plist to pre-configure multiple paths. They should not be computed and saved by the app at runtime.

Consider the following declarations:

```
let kScreenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSize(width: kScreenWidth/4, height: kScreenWidth/4))
let bottomRight = CGPoint(x: kScreenWidth - sprite.size.width/2, y: 0.0)
```

In a perfect world, I would save the following two CGPoints in the plist just as I could set positions in code and when unwrapping, the app would know to look these constants up and get their value:

(x:kScreenWidth*1/4, y: sprite.size.width/2)

bottomRight

I’m looking for a solution as close as possible!
Thanks a lot for helping out!

Comment: Have you looked into NSValue?

Comment: Hello Thomas, thanks for your reply! I try around with NSValue right now but I don't understand how I would use it in my case. In which format would I have to enter my CGPoints into the plist (I'm doing that manually to set up some preconfigured paths, which depend on the size of the screen)?

Comment: I looked into that too. NSValue does not seem to be the final path. You can not save it with NSDictionary. It must be NSData. I'm a bit stuck on how to put the one into the other. On a first guess a string parse would probably be easier. Separate be semicolon and use NSNumberFormatter

Comment: why don't you store the coordinates relatively? like, you know the point should be at `{160, 450}` coordinates on iPhone5's screen, then you need to divide the coordinates by the current screen's _width_ and _height_, like `160/320=0.5` and `450/568=0.792` and store those proportional values only in a `CGPoint`, like `{0.5, 0.792}` (you can do that) and you can calculate the final coordinates for the current screen, like for e.g. an iPhone6+ those would be `0.5*414=207` and `0.792*786=583` etc...

Comment: @holex Thanks for the suggestion! Yes, this is kind of the workaround last resort (which should work), I was hoping there'd be a more elegant way to achieve this without that kind of hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following extension:

```
extension CGPoint {
  func string() -> String { return "\(self.x);\(self.y)" }
  mutating func fromString(s:String)  {
    var coords = split(s) {$0 == ";"}
    x = CGFloat((coords[0] as NSString).floatValue)
    y = CGFloat((coords[1] as NSString).floatValue)
  }
}

let p = CGPoint(x:1.2, y:3.4)
println(p.string())
var p1 = CGPoint()
p1.fromString(p.string())
println(p1)
```

If you run that in Playground you see that there's a precision issue but with drawing coordinates you can neglect those.

Assuming you have a plist with this entry:

```
<dict>
  <key>myPoint</key>
  <string>1.2;3.4</string>
</dict>
```

After your

```
let levelDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("level\(levelNumber + 1)", ofType: "plist")!)!
```

you can unpack a `CGPoint` like

```
var p = CGPoint()
p.fromString(levelDict["myPoint"] // now it's CGPoint(x:1.2,y:3.4)
```

To save it back you need to set

```
levelDict["myPoint"] = p.string()
```

before writing the plist from the dictionary to file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that does indeed take constant variables into account! However, I'd still need to save the data as CGPoints in the plist. I guess, alternatively, it could be possible to still save the CGPoints as strings including variable names and then extending NSString to convert to CGPoint in a similar way as you did above? I'll try around and report back tonight. If I'm missing something here, please let me know, you're obviously far more experienced than I am! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The above takes into account that you save them as String in the plist. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I could not try out the code before. Thanks a lot for taking the time to type that out, much appreciated! It still does not seem to work with my computed variables. I have declared `let kScreenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
let kScreenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height` I've entered the point as a String into the plist: `kScreenWidth/2;kScreenHeight/2` Xcode will break with the fatal error:  "Cannot index empty buffer" pointing at the x = line of the CGPoint extension.

Comment: I guess the cast to NSString doesn't know how to deal with my constants?

Comment: I have updated the question to be more precise. Your solution works fine when saving the CGPoints at runtime, I'd need to have them pre-written in the plist.

Comment: Simply put in a string in the format "1.234;-9.87" to represent a CGPoint(x:1.234, y:-9.87)

Comment: But that's exactly what I can not do because it doesn't take different screen sizes into account. The CGPoint(x:160, y:240) is the center point on the iPhone 5s, but it is not on the iPhone 6 or the iPad.

Comment: Well, your original question: "I’m looking for a way to load computed CGPoints from a plist (Xcode 6 / Swift)." is answered with my question. What you're asking now is something completely different. I suggest to close this and open a new question.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, I do appreciate your help very much, but you can't reduce the question to the first line. Your solution is basically the same that I could do with CGPointFromString() (loading a string in the proper format and converting it to a CGPoint) and what I have described in the beginning of my question to not fulfill my needs.